# How to invalidate an google oauth 2.0 access token when user changes account password

Tags: cordova, oauth-2.0, ngcordova

I have the below scenario with google oauth 2.0 phonegap application

- A user logged in to my phonegap app with google oauth 2.0
- The user changes account password from website after login to the app

The issue is the user still capable of requesting google apis with the existing access token.
Please guide me the way to invalidate the access token on changing the account password

Comment: That sounds curious - i just found some other answers in the www which are saying, that all requests after a password change are invalid. Can you provide some code?

Comment: Sorry, there is no specific code to show you. It's a just login with google using oatuh 2.0. Some apps are exiting the users from app or sending some notifications when password changes. Just I want to know the way to implement.